# How to swipe away an activity to finish it

Tags: android

I know how I can change the animation between two activities. But how about:

Imagine an activity with one rectangle in the middle. If the user presses on the rectangle and swipe to top, the whole activity should swipe top (with the same speed) and finish if the user has swiped enough. I know how I can change the transitionAnim between two activities but this drives me nuts.

Using Framelayout, setting Homescreenwallpaper behind the content and make the anim on the content could be one solution, right? Are there better ways?

Could someone advise me and/or give me some tipps how I can achieve this?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but my first approach would be to attach a `GestureDetector` to the `onTouchEvent` callback of the activity. Then override the `onSwipe` callback in the listener inside `GestureDetector`. perform a translate animation in there, and when the animation reaches a particular point, I finish the activity.

Comment: That's how i solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69551226/how-to-make-viewdraghelper-works-on-activity-with-hidden-nav-bar